# Throttling limit per list in SharePoint Online

Tags: list, sharepoint-online, row-limit

Is it possible to disable the throttling limit in SPO list, using:

```
$list = $web.Lists["MyList"]
$list.EnableThrottling = $false
$list.Update()
```

as described [here](http://thesharepointfarm.com/2012/12/disable-throttling-on-a-list-by-list-basis/) or in other way?
So far my tests have shown that neither .IsThrottled nor .EnableThrottling are properties of the Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List:
[image]

but I am still asking with the faint glimmer of hope.

**I am aware this is not recommended for a variety of reasons, performance issues among others
**I am aware that this is view threshold and it is possible to create lists with over 5000 items without disabling the limit
**I am aware of multiple solutions (views, indexing, etc.) for working with lists with large number of items; this question is strictly about the possibility of disabling the view threshold

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot disable / Change it on SharePoint Online / Office 365. This is server side setting, which you need to change at Central admin or via Powershell. In O365 we don't have access to server side.

Why MSFT don't allow this on Office 365 makes sense, because this is Web App level settings, if someone changes it then all the site collections in that Web app will be affected.

Comment: Drat, I was really hoping I got the name of the property wrong :)

Comment: In addition to the answer, it can be disabled for a specific list, but you need to be Farm Admin to do so.

Comment: Which, again, I cannot be in SharePoint Online...